# Can't access in localhost

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin, database, localhost

I've gotten an error, which I can't understand anything. So, I want help from yours. I tried to access this url : http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ and get this error shown in picture.

[image: Shown this error]

Comment: Did you read the error ? Did you check your logs ? Part of the message states "No space left on device" so I am guessing your disk is full.

Comment: No space left on device would appear to be a rather large clue.  I suggest helping us help you by [edit]ing the output of `df -h` into your post.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the following procedures worked for me.

1. Open Apache configuration file using a text editor of your choice, mine is `gedit`:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```
2. Add the following line anywhere:

   ```
   Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
   ```
3. Restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```